# Environment.Newline and replace

Tags: c#, string

I am trying to allow people to throw account number into a text box and I am trying to let them enter them in several different way

IE:

```
1234
5678
9101
1213
```

Or:

```
1234,5678,9101,1112
```

But for some reason my Replace function doesn't want to respect Environment.Newline or "\r\n"

```
public string[] getAccounts()
{
    string textLines;
    string[] accounts;

    textLines = accountsTextBox.Text;
    textLines.Replace(Environment.NewLine, ",");
    accounts = textLines.Split(Environment.NewLine.ToArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    return accounts;
}
```

I grab everything from the text box into a string, then want to force everything into a comma delimited list, and finally split that list by commas.

What am I missing in my Replace?

Comment: Probably that your textbox doesn't actually have any instances of `Environment.NewLine` in it.  Perhaps it just has `"\n"` as the new line indicator, perhaps it's just `"\r"`, or perhaps it's something else entirely.  Start out by looking at the actual string and seeing what's there.

Comment: The string looks like this "1234\r\n5678\r\n" etc. @Servy

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because [String.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.replace.aspx) does not modify the original string, but rather, returns a new string.  You should update the line

```
textLines.Replace(Environment.NewLine, ",");
```

as follows:

```
textLines = textLines.Replace(Environment.NewLine, ",");
```

Additionally, you have another issue with your call to [`String.Split()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx):

It is trying to split on `Environment.NewLine.ToArray()`.  Assuming you did your replace correctly, it should have already replaced your newline characters with commas at this point, so there would be no newline delimiters left in the string.

My ultimate recommendation would be the following:

```
// At the class level
static char[] delimiters = new char[]{','};

// In your getAccounts() function
textLines = accountsTextBox.Text.Replace(Environment.NewLine, ",");
accounts = textLines.Split(delimiters, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Alternately, you could forgo the call to `String.Replace()` altogether and just update your delimiter array, like so:

```
// At the class level
static char[] delimiters = ("\r\n,").ToArray(); // treat '\r' '\n' and ',' as delimiters

// In your getAccounts() function
accounts = accountsTextBox.Text.Split(delimiters, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 textLines = textLines.Replace( ... )
```